# Check for given command-line parameters in capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm trying to give capistrano a varying number of command-line parameters. Sadly, I wasn't able to find something about this in the documentation or elsewhere on the web.

It's possible to pass parameters with:

```
cap my_task -s arg1=var1 arg2=var2
```

and then to access them via var1, var2 etc.

But I want my program to handle a dynamic amount of parameters. Is there an elegant way to access or check for all the given parameters and put them e.g. into an array or an iterable data structure?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method:

```
$ arg='foo bar baz' cap my_task
```

and then

```
ENV['arg'].split #=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my use-case with prompting the user for input via

```
Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask("TEXT:")
```

I did an until-loop with prompts to the point where the user enters a specific word ('end'). It's just a workaround but does it's job. Nevertheless I would be glad if someone could tell me how to do it like I specified in my original question.